# Invoice Automatically send before payment is successful problem

Tags: invoice, payment, magento2.4.5

I've using Pay tabs as a payment gateway for my Magento 2 store and its working perfect before but after upgrading Magento version from 2.3.1 to version 2.4.5.p1 the system send the order invoice automatically before the payment process is successful and the status of the order is canceled or pending any help on how to fix this issue please.